# How to iterate string array for one column in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have this code where `stringArray` contains 1000 words and `String[] a` contains words which are split into two columns `a[0]` and `a[1]`.

So, now `a[0]` contains all words and `a[1]` contains keys and I want to compare `a[0]` with another array. How should I do this?

```
String[] stringArray = swn.mylist.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] a = new String[stringArray.length+1];

for(String words: stringArray) {  
    a = words.split("#");
    System.out.println(a[0]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this kind of code:

```
String[] stringArray = {"Hel#lo","Wel#come","Te#st","I#n","Ja#va"};
String[] a;

for (String words : stringArray) {
    a = words.split("#");
    System.out.println(a[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` instead of `==`.

For example :

```
if(word.equals("")){
    //result
}
```